# Spring REST Docs setup MockMvc with static configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-test, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

Spring REST Docs reference guides to setting up MockMvc using autowired `ApplicationContext`:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
        .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
        .alwaysDo(document("{method-name}/{step}/")).build();
}
```

and in [this](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) blog it is described how to use static `@Configuration` classes.
However using such a static class the autowired context is not the context created from this class. It seems this class is ignored.

Is there a way to combine these two?

Comment: You'll have to show us your class-level configuration (i.e., annotations) in order for us to assist you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my configuration and it is working as expected now.

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SpringTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }

  ... test methods ...

  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package")
  @Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
  public static class Config {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("myService")
    ... replace implementation of myService with test implementation...
  }
}
```

Now the MockMvc is configured with application context created from static config class as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use @AutoConfigureRestDocs